# Onclick maximize div on other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to maximize div over other divs BUT not minimize content of other divs . I mean the content stay as it is not minimized .

Im trying this

```
 <div id="content">
    <div id="containerleft">
       <div id="box1" class="box">im left the content here to see if it minimized</div>
       <div id="box2" class="box">im middle the content here to see if it minimized</div>
       <div id="box3" class="box">im right the content here to see if it minimized</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And js code

```
   $(".box").click(function(){

var clone = $(this).clone().addClass('active');
var parent = $(this).parent();
var pos = $(this).position();

$(this).append(clone);

console.log(pos);

clone.css({'position' : 'absolute', left: pos.left + 'px', top: pos.top + 'px'}).animate({
    width: '80%', 
    height : '50%',
    top: 0,
    left: '10%'
},300);


});
```

this works perfectly with the div in the middle But not on other divs .

example if i click on right div , i want the div will maximize in its place and the other divs minimized to the left .

and if i click on left div the other will be minimized to the right.

the middle div is working good it shows in its place .
i want every div will show in its ordered place . the right will show in right , left in left , middle in middle.

Here is the [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/85mJN/187/)

Thanks for your support .

IF its fixed with css it would be better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7n8evb40/ It is a bit changed but maybe will help you.

Comment: @KIMB-technologies yes the animation is right , but the content they minimize , i dont want the content to minimize , its like the div comes over then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with css.

```js
$(".box").on('click',function(){
    $(".box").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#content{
 width:450px;
 height:150px;
 display: flex;
}

.box{
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box>div{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(450px - 40%);
    padding: 15px;
}

.box.active{
  -ms-flex: 1 1 60%;
  flex: 1 1 60%;
}

#box1{
 background:pink;
}
#box2{
 background:gray;
}

#box3{
 background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div id="box1" class="box"><div>im right the content here to see if it minimized</div></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"><div>im right the content here to see if it minimized</div></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"><div>im right the content here to see if it minimized</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: as i said to Kimb , the content are minimized , i want the content of the minimized divs stay as they are , it means the maximized div comes over them .

Comment: @ScooterDaraf edited and the content width stays the same now.

Comment: Its near of the wished result :) , but still something wrong. Before clicking the content are not full shown , they are halv hidden . i want them to be shown in whole div and when click on other divs its like jumped over it , exactly like in my fiddle in the middle one.

Comment: Ok i fixed it from your code , i had to add max-width: 150px; in  .box>div , i edit your code and add it if you mind

Comment: Thanks so much for your help .

Comment: Please i dont understand this `-webkit-box-flex` i used it with different div name and it saids unknown property , is this `box` related to the class name `box` ??

Comment: this also `display: box;` it saids invalid property

Comment: i changed the class name `box` in my divs to other name let say `myname`

Comment: this also `box-flex: 1;` unknown property , its like its related to box class or ?

Comment: I removed them, and no they are not related to the `.box` class [box-flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex). You can achieve the same results with blocks and `float: left;`.